# Actual Approver value populates before taking approval action

Tags: approval-process, approval-history

[image]When a record is submitted for approval. Let's say this approval request is assigned to 3 users. The 'Actual Approver' column in Approval History is populated with the 3 assigned user's name before actual approval action is made. 
Is this the salesforce expected behavior? 
But once the actual approval (Approve / Reject) is done by any user, the 'Actual Approver' column in Approval History is populated only with the user name who took the action. This is working as expected.
Please refer images below
[image: 1st image - When approval is pending & 2nd image - After Approval]

Comment: can you attach a picture of this issue

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Here in a single step you have assigned to user and if one of the user is approving the request the step is showing the status as approved.

If I understand correctly, you need all the assigned approvers should approve the request and then the final status should be Approved. In that case, you need to define separate approval processes.

There, after first user approves the request, you will automatically submit the request for 2nd approval through process builder.

Comment: Thanks Santanu! My apology  for the delayed response. In our scenario, we're using 'Approve / Reject record based on the first approver response'. There is no 2nd level of approval in our case. 
So, if this is the expected behavior of salesforce, then it displays the wrong information. The Actual Approver value should be populated only when the record is approved or rejected, not when the record is in pending for approval status. 
Can you please suggest whether this is the expected behavior for 'Approve/Reject record based on first response' option?
Thanks